# How to format python list in a good format result

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, format

I have many lists as shown below by printing `data` and concatenating it with a string `check_str` as shown below in the last statement. Need help in better formatting of list values after string concatenation as shown in expected

```
print(data) #printing lists in this variable
```

```
['0 rows returned']
[(Decimal('1456'),datetime.date(2022, 9, 15)), (Decimal('156'),datetime.date(2012, 10, 15))]
['0 rows returned']
['0 rows returned']
[(Decimal('1256'),datetime.date(2112, 9, 15)), (Decimal('56'),datetime.date(2012, 10, 25)), (Decimal('561'),datetime.date(2012, 10, 25))]
```

Concatenating each list with a string `check_str`

```
check_str = 'data is there'
#Below is the last statement where I am concatenating string with each list from data variable
print(check_str + '|' + ','.join(str(v) for v in data))
```

Actual output of above print statement:

```
data is there|0 rows returned
data is there|(Decimal('1456'),datetime.date(2022, 9, 15))(Decimal('156'),datetime.date(2012, 10, 15))
data is there|0 rows returned
data is there|0 rows returned
data is there|(Decimal('1256'),datetime.date(2112, 9, 15)), (Decimal('56'),datetime.date(2012, 10, 25)), (Decimal('561'),datetime.date(2012, 10, 25))
```

Expected: Need to have above output in the below good format if possible.

```
data is there|0 rows returned
data is there|1456|2022-09-15
             |156|2022-10-15
data is there|0 rows returned
data is there|0 rows returned
data is there|1256|2112-09-15
             |56|2012-10-25
             |561|2012-10-25
```

Comment: Solving the problem properly requires understanding *what the data is that you actually have*, and then coming up with a *clear specification* for what should happen. `str` is a hammer; you do not have nails or even screws, but fine china teacups. To solve the problem, start by breaking it down into logical steps. For example, take *one element, of one of the lists* in `data` that causes a problem, decide *exactly what the result should be* to format that part, and write code that handles it. Then write code to detect and address those cases. Then write code to apply that logic to everything.

Comment: I voted to close the question as "needs more focus". It is your responsibility to do that kind of analysis before posting a question. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are applying `str()` on a tuple, not on the Decimal and date values.

You would need to unpack the tuples to achieve your desired output.

Here is one solution:

```
from decimal import *
import datetime

list_of_lists = [
    ['0 rows returned'],
    [
        (Decimal('1256'),datetime.date(2112, 9, 15)), 
        (Decimal('56'),datetime.date(2012, 10, 25)), 
        (Decimal('561'),datetime.date(2012, 10, 25))
    ]
]

check_str = 'data is there'
pad_str =   '             '

for l in list_of_lists:

    if l == ['0 rows returned']:
        print('%s|%s'%(check_str, l[0]))
    else:
        prepend = check_str
        for t in l:
             print('%s|%s'%(prepend,'|'.join(str(v) for v in t)))
             prepend = pad_str
```

Comment: This is not working

Comment: When I run it using python 3.10.6 it outputs what you desired. What error are you seeing?